# Connection issues in Windows 10 but not in Linux

Tags: networking, windows-10, timeout

At home, I always have internet connection issues when using a computer running Windows 10. What happens is that when some application tries to connect to the internet, many times the connection times out. After retrying a few times, the connection is established successfully and it works for a while, then starts timing out again. For example, to access this site from my browser, I had to retry 4 or 5 times. The first times, the browser showed a "The connection has timed out" message.

I have encountered this problem with different computers, all running Windows 10. Other computers running Linux have no issues at all. I even have one that dual boots Windows 10 and Ubuntu, and I have problems on Windows but not on Ubuntu.

What could be causing this problem, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Perhaps a DNS issue? Does Windows use the same DNS as Ubuntu? for ubuntu look at https://askubuntu.com/a/152610/733411 and for Windows run in cmd `ipconfig /all` and look for the DNS entry

Comment: I'll try that and report here as soon as I get home.

Comment: I was having similar issue, since this post already here I wanted to post in MS community, here is the link https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/win10-internet-connection-problem/59141108-4477-4124-928b-3cc8ea63a322